# Aten US424 USB switch and Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: hardware, usb-hub, switches

I bought a USB switch,  an Aten US424. 
It works perfectly on every computer but not on my Raspberry Pi 3 with Retropie.

How can I solve or at least troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 1):

- [disclaimer] I don't have experience with retro-pi, but I will assume you have access to a terminal so you can run some commands to find out whats going on.
- I have successfully used a [similar USB switch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CU4QD1I) out of the box.

first check if the USB device was detected using

`lsusb`

if it not detected, it might be because of one of a few causes

- Insufficient power supply (best to use a reliable 5V/2.5A wall wart supply)
- Driver issue (unlikely given many USB devices are well supported)

Try `sudo raspi-update` to get the latest firmware updates and check again.
See [this](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) for details on what it does.
I'd recommend trying this on a spare microsd card / after backing up your card image to avoid messing up your existing setup in case something goes wrong.

Comment: You will have to `apt install usbutils` if `lsusb` isn't installed.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have been testing tonight with more attention and it seems like my problem is 100% related to damn Xbox360 Wireless Receiver.
Anything else works great :(
I also used 5v power input for my Usb Switch, no joy :(